# drizzle-spark shows the same performance results as Spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to compare the performance of Drizzle-Spark Streaming and Spark Streaming. As my workload setup i am sending Messages from Kafka. I am measuring the Throughput and Latency. As per the technical report of Drizzle-Spark, it should outperform Spark by a high margin but however, I see from my results that the Drizzle-Spark is having latency and Throughput same as that of Spark

below is my code :

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaKafkaWordCount");
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(2000));

int numThreads = 1;
Map<String, Integer> topicMap = new HashMap<>();
String[] topics = "test".split(",");
for (String topic: topics) {
  topicMap.put(topic, numThreads);
}

JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, String> messages =
KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, zooKeeper, group, topicMap);

messages.print();
jssc.start();
jssc.stop();
```

Where do i set the group size for Drizzle so more batches are included? I'm not able to figure this out.